# How to retain the value of String variables when activity is closed?

Tags: android

My string variables b,c,d,e,f stores the path of videos which I used in my gallery.But the problem is everytime my app shut down and restart again their values is lost and blank gallery is showed.I have tried making them static but through static they will retain the value for some time till the activity runs in background.Should I use onPause() and onResume() method so that they can retain their values.If yes plase suggest me code for that which i can use for retaining values of string variables when activity is closed.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("bhu",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        //Save the String value
        editor.putString("val", b).commit();
        editor.putString("val1", c).commit();
        editor.putString("val2", d).commit();
        editor.putString("val3", e).commit();
        editor.putString("val4", f).commit();

        b=prefs.getString("val", null);
        c=prefs.getString("val1", null);
        d=prefs.getString("val2", null);
        e=prefs.getString("val3", null);
        f=prefs.getString("val4", null);
```

Comment: The reason static never worked is because whenever the application was shut down, it kills all objects in memory for that application. Therefore, when you re-start the application, it would be as though you never stored anything in those static fields at all. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: @akperkins Will using SharedPreferences help to retain value even when application shut down?

Comment: Yes. It writes to a file on the device that is saved and can be loaded the next time the app is launched. @jungleboy 's answer should work.

Comment: @akperkins I tried above code posted in question but it didn't worked..is there any problem in tht code?

Comment: What is the error you are getting after applying the change?

Comment: @jungleboy no i am not getting any error but the value of variables does not retain one app shut down..i put all this inside onCreate() method..should i put first seven lines inside onStop() method?

Comment: @jungleboy Should i put the statements where i am saving data inside onStop() and statement in which i am retrieving data inside onCreate()?

Comment: thanks now its running fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to save the `String` values.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
//Save the String value
editor.putString(<Key>, <StringValue>).commit();
```

Get the `String` value:

```
String str = prefs.getString(<key>, <DefaultValue>);
```

Please note that if you are not calling `SharedPreferences` in an `Activity`,you need to call `getSharedPreferences` through a `Context`.

**[Edit]**

```
if (prefs.getString("val", "Default").equals("Default")) {
    editor.putString("val", b).commit();
}
```

Do it for other as well.

Comment: but i think sharedpreferences is used to store int .. i tried    String bhu;
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(bhu,a); but it shows "The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Comment: `SharedPreferences` can be used to store any data. Yes, even custom data can be stored. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: it shows "The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)".can u plzz suggest me code for tht..i am fresher

Comment: Use `getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);`

Comment: I tried the above code posted in question but it didn't work..is there any problem in tht code?

Comment: You were first setting the value, and then retrieving it. It was like: int i = 10; i = 20; So, you will always get 20. You should set the value only if it was not set earlier. You missed to put this check.

Comment: then i tried setting value inside onStop() method and retrieving it inside onCreate() method..that also worked